# c# download large csv file from DataTable and MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, csv

I can't download dynamically create CSV file from **DataTable** in ASP.Net using C#.

The number of row extracted with sql query are 831, but the output not working and the webpage not responding.

I have tried with add LIMIT 10 on the query and the download worked.

Any suggestion?

My code below.

Thank you in advance for any help, really appreciated.

```
string sqlXls = @String.Format(" SELECT * FROM doTable; ");

using (OdbcConnection con =
  new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnMySQL"].ConnectionString))
{
    using (OdbcCommand cmd =
        new OdbcCommand(sqlXls, con))
    {
        try
        {
            cmd.Connection.Open();

            using (OdbcDataAdapter sda = 
                new OdbcDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;

                using (DataTable dt = 
                    new DataTable())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);

                    string csv = string.Empty;

                    foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        csv += column.ColumnName + ',';
                    }

                    csv += "\r\n";

                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                        {
                            csv += row[column.ColumnName].ToString().Replace(",", ";") + ',';
                        }

                        csv += "\r\n";
                    }

                    Response.Clear();
                    Response.Buffer = true;
                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=SqlExport.csv");
                    Response.Charset = "";
                    Response.ContentType = "application/text";
                    Response.Output.Write(csv);
                    Response.Flush();
                    Response.End();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("operation failed!", ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            cmd.Connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error that your getting, please post it!

Comment: @iceDragon Thank you, but I don't have error ... the webpage not responding after click on download file CSV, but export CSV file if in the query add LIMIT 10.

Comment: What happens if there is any column in your datatable that happens to have a null-value? My guess is that your first ten records don't have any `null` but somewhere they exist.

Comment: Ok then could you please provide the csv content as a string in order for me  to test it

Comment: I do not think it is the cause of the problem (831 lines is not that much data) so I am not writing this as an answer. But this is a rather obvious situation where you should either use a StringBuilder, or write the csv content to the output stream as it is being generated instead of repeatedly adding to the csv string.

Comment: Use CSVHelper: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/